# Button Href to press submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, href

I was just wondering how to go about getting a href to press a button.I want to get btn btn primary when pressed to: press the submit button.

```
<BODY>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#Home"><span class="fui-time"></span></a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#School"><span class="fui-time"></span></a>
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="options" id="Home" value="1" />Home
    <input type="submit" name="options" id="School" value="2" />School
    <input type="submit"  name="options" id="Work" value="3" />Work

</form>


</BODY>
```

Thank-you.Also if you could also provide a in-depth explanation that would be great as I sort of new to javascript.

PS: Is there any way to do it without using the function onClick()

Comment: you wan to submit the form when you click in <a> tag ?

Comment: Question unclear. Please update clearly.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$('.btn.btn-primary').click(function (ev) {
    $(this.href).click();
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Although I would say your markup and structure are quite strange, you want to have submit buttons and then links that cause those buttons to be clicked??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <BODY>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#Home" onClick="formSubmit()"><span class="fui-time"></span></a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#School" onClick="formSubmit()"><span class="fui-time"></span></a>
        <form id="myform">
          <input type="submit" name="options" id="Home" value="1" />
          Home
          <input type="submit" name="options" id="School" value="2" />
          School
          <input type="submit"  name="options" id="Work" value="3" />
          Work
        </form>
        </BODY>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function formSubmit(){
        $("#myform").submit();
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript in a link like this `<a href="javascript:alert('javascript go')">`

Edit: as  susheel pointed out this is not a good idea, its much better to just bind or use onClick to trigger the button click.

It would be better to do something like this:

`<div onclick="document.myform.submit()"></div>` (if you are submitting a form).  There is no way to replace a button with another element with raw html.  You will need to use javascript one way or another.

Comment: I agree, its just he asked how to do it without using onclick, and that's how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

check the below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Q4Va/3/

```
$('.btn.btn-primary').on('click',function () {
    $(this.href).click();
});
```